# Vector operator [ ] out of range leads to a crash?

Tags: c++, vector, error-handling

```
vector<int> iV2_func{2, 3, 4, 5};
drucke(iV2_func);
  for (j=0; j<=iV2_func.size(); j++) { 
    iV2_func[j] = quadfunc(iV2_func[j]+1);
 }
 drucke(iV2_func);
```

I'm currently practicing for my upcoming C++ exam and since I grew up with Java I'm not familiar with all of C++'s customs.
The given code is in a `main()`-Method, everything necessary has been included etc.
The task was to detect errors in six for-loops that used different means to multiply the parameter with itself, such as a macro, a template, an inline-function etc.
`drucke()` prints the single members of the vector.
This for-loop here obviously is out of bounds, but since the `.at()`-Method is not used, no exception is thrown and instead we end up having undefined behaviour.

When I start the program, the program crashes *after* all lines have been printed. Even the for-loops *after* this for-loop right here are being run through and everything gets printed. It seems the error occurs at the end of the main()-method and not when the program accesses the index that is out of range, but the fault definitely lies in that index, because the program does not crash otherwise. So how exactly is it that the program seems to work with that code but still crashes at the end?

Comment: it has undefined behavior, which means that literally *anything* might happen.

Comment: _Vector `operator [ ]` out of range leads to a crash_ I knew this'd be good!

Comment: Code with bugs in it will not behave as you expect. This is why we fix bugs.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant but is this undefined behaviour constant? I thought it would change all the time, since otherwise you could define it.

Comment: @Grougal "anything might happen" includes "it may do the same erroneous operation each time". "undefined" means that you **cannot *possibly* assume anything about the behavior,** and thus it's **completely pointless to try speculate about it.**

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I see, that definitely makes sense. But is the answer to my question now undefined behaviour or what datenwolf below anwsered (as a safety measure)? Both sound plausible to me.

Comment: @Grougal the answer to your question is that undefined behavior happened to behave in some particular way in your case, and knowing the compiler, the architecture, the OS, etc. it might be possible to explain that specific piece of behavior in your case. that might not be possible in other cases, though (let alone in general).

Answer (score 1):

> So how exactly is it that the program seems to work with that code but still crashes at the end?

Most likely you've compiled your program in a debug build configuration. In debug builds the "perimeter" of allocated memory regions is often filled with canary values so that OOB writes can be detected upon memory deallocation. When such a killed canary is detected the memory deallocator will abort the program.

Why the need for canary values? Because on modern OSs memory allocation and protection happens only with page granularity, usually 4k. So as long as your memory access stays within the bounds of the OS supplied mapping (which is a multiple of the page size) the OS can't detect the illegal access. However memory allocators will pool allocations within those pages, and since there's no protection between objects within such a region, OOB access that clobbers the "neighbours" are hard to detect. Hence the canary values, so that in development such OOB accesses can be reported.

Comment: So basically it is a safety-measure that detects that something was written OOB. I think I get it now. Thank you!

Comment: @Grougal: Not so much a safety feature, but a debugging helper. Don't rely on that behavior, because it's implementation defined and only there as a courtsey to make you aware of a problem with your code.